# How to Traverse Non-Select Dropdown using selenium?

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I am trying to get all the options available in a KendoUI dropdown which uses 'k-dropdown' as its control rather than a 'select'. Therefore, I cannot use something like (since there is no select element):

```
    public void ChooseOrderType(string type)
    {
        var mySelect = new SelectElement(TypeDropDownLocator);
        var options = mySelect.Options;
        foreach (var option in options) {
            if (option.Text.Equals(type))
                option.Click();
        }

    }
```

HTML:

```
<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="orderStatus_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="orderStatus_option_selected">
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-input">All orders</span>
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
            <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input id="orderStatus" name="orderStatus" type="text" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
    </span>
```

Is there any way to traverse this manually to get all the options?

EDIT: I got it working with JeffC's method:

```
public ViewOrdersPage SearchDraftOrders(string type)
{
    TypeDropDownLocator.Click();
    Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("id('orderStatus_listbox')/li[2]")).Click();
    SearchOrdersButton.Click();
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, you won't be able to use the `SelectElement` type. You will need to instead treat it like any other element. You will need to click the SELECT-like element to open the dropdown and then click the element that represents the OPTION-like element you want selected. You may need a short wait between the two clicks, depending on the speed of the dropdown opening.

Without seeing the entirety of the HTML used for the dropdown and options, I can't provide code but you can likely figure it out on your own give the directions above.

Comment: I am trying to do this using xPath as such: '    TypeDropDownLocator.Click();
            Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("span[.='Draft orders']")).Click();' but am unable to find the correct xpath, can anyone help out w/ the above markup?